# Firefox add-on: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource (Reason: CORS header ‘Origin’ cannot be added)

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, firefox-addon, cross-domain, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an extension that I develop for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tf2center-tools/oagdkccjchnflfcikaagcelgipminjhd) and also upload to [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tf2center-tools/)'s add-on store. I recently added a feature where the extension makes a cross-domain request to https://tf2metrics.azurewebsites.net to download some json data.

Sample call from the extension:

https://tf2metrics.azurewebsites.net/api/users/76561198142328193,76561198200094518,76561198090551717

The same source code works fine on Chrome, but not for Firefox users.

In the Firefox browser console, this call results in:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://tf2metrics.azurewebsites.net/api/users/76561198142328193,76561198200094518,76561198090551717. (Reason: CORS header ‘Origin’ cannot be added).`

My content script runs on https://tf2center.com/lobbies/* with a simple line of jQuery:

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
    // do stuff
});
```

I tried adding an `Origin` header since the error says it "cannot be added":

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'Origin': "https://tf2center.com"
    }
});
```

This extension still does not work on Firefox and additionally fails on Chrome with this call. Error is:

`Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"`

So I removed that. I browsed a bit and saw that adding

```
"permissions": [
  "*://*.tf2center.com/*",
  ...
],
```

to my `manifest.json` might resolve the issue, but that does not work either.

For reference here is the ASP.NET Core 3.1 `Startup.cs` code that I originally added to handle CORs when I first needed to support the feature for Chrome:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseCors(_ => _.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
    ...
}
```

Why does my Chrome extension allow the call and Firefox does not? What else could I try to fix the Firefox-specific error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I misunderstood what needed to be added to the `manifest.json`'s `permissions` section. I need to include the URL match pattern I wish to call, not the origin's URL.

```
"permissions": [
  "https://tf2metrics.azurewebsites.net/*",
  ...
],
```

I updated to specifically only `https` calls on my site (not the calling site) and it works now on Firefox.